# .htaccess subdomain wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've been looking thru many, many different ways of doing a mod_rewrite in my .htaccess for creating wildcard subdomains that forward to a specific path, while preserving the trailing url for directory and page. Nothing seems to do the trick. I'm just not that good at regular expressions yet to figure this out.

My wildcard needs to make:

http://username.domain.org/project1/hello.html

the same as:

http://domain.org/domains/username/project1/hello.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.org/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```